# What should I do with data and materials?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Since the latest update I collected a lot of "materials" and "data".

I found materials after destroying a ship and they often consisted of former parts of the ship, e.g. shield emitters or hull alloys.

Data was collected when I scanned other ships and in one case by finding a data beacon after following an Unidentified Signal Source.

These materials and data don't use any cargo space, but I don't know what to do with them. Selecting them in my inventory displays a message regarding engineers, but I haven't found any yet.

Where do I find engineers? What can they do with these materials/data?

If I don't want to give them my materials/data, can I sell them?

Comment: Which version of Elite: Dangerous do you have? Xbox or PC? Do you have Horizons (aka Season 2), or just the base game (season 1)?

Comment: Xbox One and I don't think Horizons is out on Xbox yet. Haven't bought it yet though. Will I need to buy Horizons to fully benefit from Materials and Data?

Comment: Yes. And Horizons comes out for Xbox in a couple days. Without horizons, you can use materials (mostly minerals/metals) for synthesizing restocks of various things (including upgraded ammo) and SRV repairs, but not really anything else. With Horizons, you can use materials and data to get things engineered on your ships for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are used in synthesis (in the cargo screen) and by engineers. When you get the engineers update you'll be introduced to a few of them, and then have to find others.

Synthesis lets you craft ammo and jump-boosts.

Engineers mod and enhance your kit for you, but it's a dice roll each time exactly how good it is.

Materials don't use up cargo, but annoyingly there's still a limit (600 I think) of how many you can carry.

Comment: Do you know by chance if I you can craft torpedos? My torpedo pylon holds one torpedo and each shot costs me 15.000 cr. Would be nice to craft torpedos between battles.

Comment: I don't know, but generally torpedoes are very poor - for their cost they should be devastating, but they're not. They're useless against shields and do less damage than a large frag salvo or 3 cannon hits.

Comment: I normally use them after the shields are down as a "fire-and-forget" method to buy me some time. On low class shields they do enough damage, but I should think about getting a cannon.. Are there gimbled cannons?

Comment: @exa yeah, though on the whole multicannon are better as gimballed.

Comment: I think I'm gonna replace the torpedo by a multicannon. Damn I need more hardpoints... I'm stuck with a Cobra MkIII and the Python is SO far away. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @exa forget about the Python for now - if you're into combat your next ship should be a Vulture, and they eat Pythons. The Python is 50 mill to buy but you need 250 mill to get it decent and a 20 mill Vulture will have an easy win until that. Always go for larger kinetic weapons, as hull damage is nerfed by weapon size but shields are not. Check out some of my other Elite answers for more detail :-)

Comment: 250 mil holy... Made only 600k yesterday. How do people get 250mil? I'm definitely into combat but I would like to aim for a multi-purpose ship since I'm also doing a fair amount of trading.

Comment: @exa you should be able to make about 1-2 million per hour. I prefer bounty hunting, but mining or trade can make that too. In fact trade is probably the most profitable, if a little dull, if you find a really profitable route. Community goals can be very lucrative too - you can double your money with them. I find it better to either trade or fight - multipurpose ships don't really do either as well, you'll make money quicker with a ship dedicated to one or the other. Try a cheap Viper in a nav beacon or high res with a warrant scanner and you should be able to make 1 million an hour easy

Comment: Materials do take up cargo (in 2.3) the limit is 1000.

Comment: Materials don't take up *cargo space* (i.e. cargo racks). If you have no cargo space you can still carry them.